# JsonSyntaxException on game launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't play Minecraft 1.8.3 because this happens whenever Minecraft is getting launched:

**Game Output**

```
[16:10:30] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: MrGriefer_
[16:10:30] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is` token:30b49928cfee405d8fe152cdcefe29fe:b9749246e9ac452eb4561a5f6346546f)
Exception in thread "Client thread" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at lu.b(SourceFile:151)
    at lu.<init>(SourceFile:43)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.<init>(SourceFile:155)
    at bpp.<init>(SourceFile:41)
    at avf.<init>(SourceFile:293)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    ... 7 more
```

**Launcher Log**

```
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-32.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.17\authlib-1.5.17.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-32.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:26 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.7.13\realms-1.7.13.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:27 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that
[16:10:27 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Used own copy as it matched etag
[16:10:27 INFO]: Job 'Version & Libraries' finished successfully (took 0:00:02.261)
[16:10:27 INFO]: Launching game
[16:10:27 INFO]: Unpacking natives to C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3-natives-645498046609
[16:10:27 INFO]: Launching in C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
[16:10:27 INFO]: Half command: C:\Program Files\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x32\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3-natives-645498046609 -cp C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.17\authlib-1.5.17.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.7.13\realms-1.7.13.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar;C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main
[16:10:27 INFO]: Looking for orphaned versions to clean up...
[16:10:29 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...
[16:10:30 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
[16:10:30 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[16:10:30 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3-natives-645498046609
```

- Minecraft 1.8.3 was working before, but now this happens whenever I launch the game!
- Other versions of Minecraft are working fine, except for 1.8.X.
- My Java version is: Version 8 update 40.
- My Windows version is: Windows 7.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the Game output instead of using a screenshot. A bit of the error is cut off. Use code formatting (the **{ }** button). Furthermore, did it work before? Or on other versions of the game? Also, make sure to mention your Java version, your Windows version, and I suggest changing the title to "JsonSyntaxException on game launch"

Comment: Can someone remove the [on hold] i edited the question!

Comment: ```Finished downloading C:\Users\Karamela\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Used own copy as it matched etag``` please delete that file, then re-launch Minecraft.

Comment: @Thebluefish I deleted 1.8.3.jar and the 1.8.3.json and its still crashes my game!

Comment: anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Press your Windows+R keys, type in %AppData% at the dialog, and press Enter. In the window that appears, open the .minecraft directory

Just delete everything except your saves. It will re-download what it needs when you attempt to Play it.

-HeCedSo